# how to use spatial mapping on immersive headset with MixedRealityToollkit

Tags: virtual-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I'm trying to use MixedRealityToollkitin Unity to render spatial mapping data in the same way a hololens does, but using a windows full immersion headset, not a hololens. The prefabs for hololens works for running the full immersive headset, but using the spatial mapping prefab, like I would with hololens does nothing.

Comment: While the "Mixed Reality" tag suggests that the Windows Mixed Reality (WMR) headsets are AR/MR devices, they are really more VR devices.  If you are doing AR, your design will usually be on a hololens, and if doing VR you'll end up on the Windows Mixed Reality headsets.  If you need Spatial mapping, I think your choice of platform may be wrong, but can't really say without more information.

Answer (score 3):

Spatial Mapping is not supported on WMR Immersive headsets, sorry.

You can also find which other parts of the MixedRealityToolkit support which devices, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity).  Under "Feature areas" there are icons showing compatibility.